# Offset to symbol in WMS request

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

Is it possible to give offset to symbol of point feature  using sld in openlayers or geoserver?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the offset function on point, line and polygon features in GeoServer to style your WMS. Below is an example of how to use the offset function with a point feature in SLD:

```
<PointSymbolizer>
<Geometry>
<ogc:Function name="offset">
    <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Literal>-100</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
</Geometry>
<Graphic>
  <Mark>
    <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
    <Fill>
      <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter>
    </Fill>
    <Stroke>
      <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
      <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
    </Stroke>
  </Mark>
  <Size>6</Size>
</Graphic>
</PointSymbolizer>
```

You can see more on [GeoServer and Geometry transformations in SLD](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/geometry-transformations.html#drop-shadow).